# What's the best way to build a Flask API to control and show the status of a program tool I have built?

Tags: python, flask

I've developed a backend project using Python. It collects data from different sources, process the data, and then perform actions with it (for example, store relevant info in a database). To execute it, I just do `python main.py` and it starts the daemon process.

Now I want to add a Flask API in order to interact with this collector: start/stop the collection, see the state of each component, add/remove components... What is the best approach to do it? I can't just add Flask app object and routes to the same project, because when I deploy the Api using Gunicorn with several workers, it runs several instances of the collector.

For example: I have in the collector a object called `GlobalManager` that is in charge of creating, deleting, starting and stoping the collector's components. Obviously, there is only one instance of this `GlobalManager`, so I can't include it in a project with Flask, because if I run it with Gunicorn, it starts several instances of the `GlobalManager`.

Should I code the API in a separate project and the communicate both the API and the collector through some tool?